# How to add value to an array of object in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, soap

I am consuming a third party web service and I want to add value to match the service reference class, and i am not sure how to add value to the following:

in reference:

```
public partial class UserInfor: object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
        private ABC[] listOfABCField;

        public ABC[] ListOfABC 
    {
            get {
                return this.listOfABCField;
            }
            set {
                this.listOfABCField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ListOfABC");
            }
        }
}

public partial class ABC : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private string ipField;

private string fristNameField;

private string lastNameField;       

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
in my service.asmx file have tried to put value as below:
in below code i got exception in line ABC[] abc=new ABC[0]; error code:(NullReferenceException)

```
    UserInfor user = new UserInfor();
    ABC[] abc=new ABC[0];
        abc[0].firstName= "petter";
        abc[0].lastName = "lee";

        user.ListOfABC = abc[1];
```

i also tried 
in below code i got exception in line user.ListOfABC[0] = abc;  error code:(NullReferenceException)

```
    UserInfor user = new UserInfor();
    ABC abc=new ABC[0];
        abc.firstName= "petter";
        abc.lastName = "lee";

        user.ListOfABC[0] = abc;
```

any idea how to add abc to user class ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, first instantiate the array, if you know in advance how many items it would contain then specify that as well in the square brackets like:

```
ABC[] abc=new ABC[1]; // this array will contain 1 item maximum
```

now instantiate that item and then set values of properties :

```
    abc[0] = new ABC(); // instantiating first item of array which is at 0th index
    abc[0].firstName= "petter";
    abc[0].lastName = "lee";
```

If you don't know how many item would come in it, then go with [@David's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41381108/1875256) of using `List<T>`

Comment: thank you for your comment, but how about the user class ? how to add abc to user class?

Comment: user.ListOfABC[0] = abc;

Answer (score 3):

This'll probably be easier if you use a `List<>` instead of an array.  Change the property:

```
private List<ABC> listOfABCField;

public List<ABC> ListOfABC
{
    // etc.
}
```

Don't forget to initialize it in the class' constructor so it's not null:

```
public UserInfor()
{
    listOfABCField = new List<ABC>();
}
```

Then you can just add an object to it, which doesn't need any of the array syntax you were trying to use:

```
UserInfor user = new UserInfor();
ABC abc = new ABC();
abc.firstName= "petter";
abc.lastName = "lee";

user.ListOfABC.Add(abc);
```

Comment: David thabk you so much ..But the thing is that I am consuming a third party web service and the reference class above is generated by import wsdl file ... preferablely not to change any structure ...